# What's the reason for this Invalid Layer "Cannot open GDAL dataset ..." error

Tags: qgis, python, raster, error

When adding a rasterfile with QGIS python console there appears an error when the first letter of a rasterfile to be added is not written in capital letters. Why this behaviour?

**Example case1:**

```
>>> qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("C:\geodaten\natural_earth.tif", "raster")
```

*Error:*

> Invalid Layer "Cannot open GDAL dataset C:\geodaten atural_earth.tif:
>   `C:\geodaten atural_earth.tif' does not exist in the file system, and
>   is not recognised as a supported dataset name."

**Example case2:**

```
>>> qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("C:\geodaten\Natural_earth.tif", "raster")
```

*No error!*

Rasterlayer is added properly.

With vectorlayers the above mentioned problem doesn't exist.
The QGIS version in use is 2.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the API is fine what is happening is Python is seeing \n and treating it as a new line which is what \n means. You will need to put a r in the front of your string. (r"c:\yourpwth")